# How can i get id ofparent onclick of child

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get id of list item onclick of anchor. I want to display id of list item via Javascript alert. Here is my source:

Comment: `this.parentNode.id;` will work if you call `myClickFunction` properly, i.e. `myClickFunction.call(this)`.

Comment: @FelixKling Is `.call(this)` required? From what I know `this` is already the clicked element.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: In the OP's case `this` will be `window`. Only inside the event handler will `this` refer to the element. However, `myClickFunction` is not the event handler, it is called *from* the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), use `parent()` and `attr()` functions:

```
function myClickFunction(){
   var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.parent()` and `.attr()` or `[0].id` as follows:

```
$('.child').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).parent()[0].id; //or $(this).parent().attr('id');
});
```

You would do well not to use inline `JS`.

```js
$(function() {
    $('ul a').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).parent()[0].id; //or $(this).parent().attr('id');
        alert( id );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="li1"><a>Click1</a></li>
<li id="li2"><a>Click2</a></li>
<li id="li3"><a>Click3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some thing like this ..

```
<script>
function myClickFunction(a){
var id = a.parentNode.id;
alert("I just clicked list item: " + id);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li id=li1"><a onClick="myClickFunction(this);">Click1</a></li>
<li id=li2"><a onClick="myClickFunction(this);">Click2</a></li>
<li id=li3"><a onClick="myClickFunction(this);">Click3</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why should the OP do that? They seem to be a beginner, so I think they'd appreciate some explanation.

Comment: Actually I have seen your Explanation @FelixKling So I think it will be better if I provide some sample code so that they will look at